# MySQL Selecting data, not repeating ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, group-by

I've got 3 tables:

1. workers with fields: worker_id, name, surname,
2. tasks with fields: task_id, tasks_name,
3. table implementing, which contains worker_id and task_id

I have to select `worker_id`, `name`, `surname`, and `task_name`. The problem is that I don't know how to not duplicate worker_id while I'm selecting data (I have to show all the task of worker).

I came up with one query but as i mentioned before it doesn't work for me well (it repeats id of workers)

```
SELECT workers.worker_id, workers.name, workers.surname, tasks.tasks_name 
FROM workers, tasks, implementing 
WHERE workers.worker_id=implementing.worker_id AND tasks.task_id=implementing.task_id
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. If a worker has several tasks, how do you want to represent that on a single row?

Comment: This is a join syntax that was used in the 1980s. How old *are* you??? Use explicit joins (`inner join`, `left outer join`, etc.) that made it into the SQL standard in 1992.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get something like

```
+-----------+------+---------+-----------+
| worker_id | name | surname | task_name |
+-----------+------+---------+-----------+
|         1 | John | Smith   | TASK A    |
|         1 | John | Smith   | TASK B    |
|         2 | Jane | Miller  | TASK C    |
+-----------+------+---------+-----------+
```

And this is exactly how it should be. SQL queries return tables of columns and rows. A row's data would be incomplete without the worker information. You can suppress this with `CASE` expressions and the analytic `LAG` function (available as of MySQL 8), but you should rather do this in your app or Website where you show the data. (This is also the place where you'd decide whether to display a comma or a dot for a decimal separator for instance.) SQL ist the data supplier, your app cares about the presentation.

Anyway, here is a query that does this in MySQL 8:

```
select 
  case when w.worker_id = lag(w.worker_id) over (order by w.worker_id, t.task_id) then null else w.worker_id end as worker_id,
  case when w.worker_id = lag(w.worker_id) over (order by w.worker_id, t.task_id) then null else w.name end as name,
  case when w.worker_id = lag(w.worker_id) over (order by w.worker_id, t.task_id) then null else w.surname end as surname,
  t.tasks_name
from workers w
join implementing i on i.worker_id = w.worker_id
join tasks t on t.task_id = i.task_id
order by w.worker_id, t.task_id;
```

```
+-----------+------+---------+-----------+
| worker_id | name | surname | task_name |
+-----------+------+---------+-----------+
|         1 | John | Smith   | TASK A    |
|           |      |         | TASK B    |
|         2 | Jane | Miller  | TASK C    |
+-----------+------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. That's what i wanted to get :)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that i don't know how to not duplicate worker_id while i'm selecting data (i have to show all the task of worker).

It looks like you want string aggregation. You can put all tasks of each worker in a single column as a comma-separated list with `group_concat()`.

You can do this with joins, or with a correlated subquery, like so:

```
select
    w.worker_id,
    w.name,
    w.surname,
    (
        select group_concat(t.task_name)
        from implementing i
        inner join tasks t on t.task_id = i.task_id
        where i.worker_id = w.worker_id
    ) task_names
from worker w
```

Note that this uses standard, explicit joins (with the `on` keyword) rather than old-school, implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause): this syntax from decades ago makes queries harder to follow and maintain, and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Why the downvote? This looks perfectly fine to me. (And anyway, it is impolite and not at all helpful to downvote an answer and not explain why.)